# Xamarin.Forms How to make x:Name= available for several files?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

in one of the **xaml** files I have a Collection View that has the name x:Name="name_colec"
and I can s refer to this name in the **cs** file that belongs to the current **xaml** file in which I defined this name. but how to make this name available not only for the current cs file, but also for other project files? because I ran into a problem that I can't refer to this name in other cs files.

Comment: I think we need to know what exactly you're wanting to do.  This is not something you should need to do.

Comment: @Skin I have a main page and a pop-up window. I entered the data into a pop-up window and now I want to create an entry in the database based on it, which will be displayed in the Collection View, which is located on the main page.

Comment: @Skin but the name_collec  is not visible in the popup files. Only in the main page files.

Comment: So you want to navigate back to the main page from your pop up page and populate the collection view with the data from pop up page?

Comment: this is NOT the way to solve this and is a bad idea.  Pass a model object to your popup and use binding to update its values.  When the popup dismisses the parent page will still have a reference to the populated model object.